# How vim does search */#

Tags: vim

When I do a `*` or `#` search on a character, it pulls out the word, such as:

```
/\<data\>
```

Why does it use that instead of searching on something like:

```
\bdata\b
```

From doing `:h *` it shows:

> Only whole keywords are searched for, like with the command `"/\<keyword\>"`.

But I'm not quite sure how to interpret that. How would `\<` be related to a word boundary, `\b` ?

Comment: \<\> is used to for visual selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would \< be related to a word boundary, \b ?

The answer is very simple. `\b` comes from Perl, and Perl regex is not compatible with Vi (not the other way round, as Vi is older than Perl). So `\<` and `\>` are left and right word boundaries in Vi regex flavour.

Comment: thanks, is there a part in the documentation/help that shows that part? Also, what about the comment by HeisAif -- he mentions it is for visual selection?

Comment: @David542 a) Make sure you've read `:h help-context` (also see `:h 02.8`): to find regex you need to enter `:h /\<`. b) Visual selection is delimited with automatic marks < and >. However, mark position is referred (in certain contexts) with tick or backtick, never a backslash.